# sqlite3 group by

Tags: database, sqlite, group-by

I have 2 tables fun (master) and blk (slave).

```
sqlite> select * from fun;
id          mod_id      name         freq      
----------  ----------  -----------  ----------
1           1           adpcm_coder  99108     
2           1           adpcm_decod  0
```

I want to count how many blk's there are for fun, so I use "group by":

```
sqlite> SELECT fun.*, count(blk.id) as no_blk FROM fun, blk WHERE fun.id=blk.fun_id GROUP BY (blk.fun_id);
id          mod_id      name         freq        no_blk     
----------  ----------  -----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           adpcm_coder  99108       12
```

The 2nd  row is rejected since blks for it do not exists. 
**Howto get result like this?**

```
id          mod_id      name         freq        no_blk     
----------  ----------  -----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           adpcm_coder  99108       12        
2           1           adpcm_decod  0           0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an `OUTER JOIN`.
Also you should `GROUP BY` all non-aggregated columns in your `SELECT` clause.

Try something like this:

```
  SELECT fun.id, fun.mod_id, fun.name, fun.freq, count(blk.id) as no_blk 
    FROM fun
         LEFT OUTER JOIN blk
         ON blk.fun_id = fun.id
GROUP BY fun.id, fun.mod_id, fun.name, fun.freq;
```

Comment: thx adam. It works just fine. Could explain why I have to use in a group-by all non-aggregated columns? Is it because some of them can have null values? thx.

Comment: Cheers, mate. Taking another look at your query it appears that, with `fun.*`, that you were in fact grouping-by all non-aggregated columns.  If you hadn't done so, you would likely notice that your resultset would be smaller than expected.

Answer (score 1):

Adam is correct; another approach:

```
SELECT fun.*, count(blk.id) as no_blk FROM fun, blk 
WHERE fun.id=blk.fun_id GROUP BY (blk.fun_id) 
UNION 
SELECT fun.*, 0 as no_blk FROM fun, blk 
WHERE fun.id not in (SELECT fun.id from fun, blk WHERE fun.id=blk.fun_id);
```